# Azure 2016 Single Domain controller

Tags: azure, domain-controller, windows-server-2016

I have installed a single 2016 domain controller within Azure, when I attempt to login it tells me my domain administrator password has expired and needs to be changed, but as I can only remote to it via RDP it doesn't give me the option to change the password, I have no workstations attached to the domain so cannot login via those.
The azure password reset will only do local accounts which do not exist as its now a DC, so I appear to be stuck unless there's some kind of powershell script that can be used to force a change of the domain admin password(I have found scripts for local users but not domain accounts), any ideas on how to access this VM?
Thanks

Comment: Try to upload custom scripts Extension to your VM with this `.ps1` file : `$secpwd= ConvertTo-SecureString -String "<your new password>" -AsPlainText -Force    Set-ADAccountPassword Administrator -NewPassword $secpwd -Reset       Set-ADUser Administrator -ChangePasswordAtLogon $false`

I did not test it ,if you have any process, please let me know. Hope this helps!

Comment: If this works - it should be the answer

Answer (score 0):

I lost my domain this way. In addition to the expired password, I also had LAPS installed which means I didn't know the local admin password to any of the machines. Always leave a backdoor.